# RxJS equivalent of `Bacon.when()` with properties (which are sampled but not part of the synchronization pattern)

Tags: javascript, frp, rxjs, bacon.js

Consider the following Bacon.js code sample (loosely based on [the code here](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#join-patterns-and-properties), uses [bacon.model](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.model) & [bacon.jquery](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.jquery)):

```
<input id="total" type="text" placeholder="total">
/
<input id="quantity" type="text" placeholder="quantity" value="1">
=
<span id="price"></span>
<script>

  var $total = Bacon.$.textFieldValue($("#total")).changes();

  var quantity = Bacon.$.textFieldValue($("#quantity"));

  var price = Bacon.when(
    [$total, quantity], function(x,y) { return x/y; }
  ).toProperty(0);

  price.onValue(function (p) {
    $('#price').text(p);
  });

</script>
```

What happens here is that the stream `$total` and the property `quantity` are joined into a property `price`. Both `$total` and `quantity` get their input from a text input field, but only `$total` prompts `price` to be updated. (I.e. `quantity` is sampled but not part of the synchronization pattern.)

I am trying to achieve this same behavior using RxJS instead of Bacon.js, but all I can come up with is super ugly solutions. I reckon I must be overlooking something…?

My best shot so far (behavior not identical, but you get the idea):

```
var totalChange = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#total'), 'input');

var totalValue = totalChange.map(function () {
  return parseInt($('#total').val(), 10);
});
var quantityValue = totalChange.map(function () {
  return parseInt($('#quantity').val(), 10);
});

var price = Rx.Observable.zip(
  totalValue,
  quantityValue,
  function (x,y) {
    return x/y;
  }
);

price.subscribe(function (p) {
  $('#price').text(p);
});
```

Because neither `combineLatest` or `zip` offer the desired behavior on observables that represent the two text fields directly, all I can think of is to create an observable for quantity based on input events in the text field for total. Which works, but it feels pretty far-fetched.

Any suggestions for alternative approaches?

Comment: I've changed my answer below. `combineLatest` is the equivalent of Bacon's `when` apparently. [I found this out just now by submitting an issue that made me look dumb](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/524) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the recently added [`withLatestFrom`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/withlatestfrom.md) instead of `combineLatest`.

```
var price = totalValue.withLatestFrom(quantityValue, (x,y) => x/y);
```

Compare their diagrams:

- http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest
- http://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom
- http://rxmarbles.com/#zip

Comment: Oooo... I didn't know about withLatestFrom. Very nice

Comment: Time semantics of withLatestFrom are the same as map operator, therefore `price` emits only when `totalValue` emits.

Comment: Hold on, while examining that, it seems it only emits when the observable `withLatestFrom` is operating on emits. I'm unsure that's really what the OP is asking for, even though in his example he has only one source observable.

Comment: In the scenario when you want a price to update with any change to each of it's source observables, you'd need to either merge them all together and use withLatestFrom, or do something like the scan I showed below.

Comment: He said "only $total prompts price to be updated. (I.e. quantity is sampled but not part of the synchronization pattern.)". Seems to be the case for `withLatestFrom`.

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT: [combineLatest](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md) seems to be the equivalent of bacon's when.

I think maybe you're looking to do something like this?

```
var totalChange = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#total'), 'input');

var totalValue = totalChange.map(function () {
  return parseInt($('#total').val(), 10);
});

var quantityValue = totalChange.map(function () {
  return parseInt($('#quantity').val(), 10);
});

Observable.combineLatest(totalValue, quantityValue, function(total, quantity) {
  return total / quantity;
});
```

Unfortunately, that's the prettiest thing I can think of to answer the spirit of your question.

In reality though, given the example, you'd just do this:

```
var price = totalChange.map(function() {
  return parseInt($('#total').val(), 10) / parseInt($('#quantity').val(), 10);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I just realized this solution is at the bottom of Ben Lesh's answer.  I'll leave this here just for the wordier explanation.**

If a variable isn't reactive, sometimes the simplest solution is to just acknowledge that and not try to react to it.

Since `quantity` is not observable, any attempts to make it observable and then combining 2 observable streams is just going to feel hackish.

Instead I'd just embrace its unobservable-ness and use `map` to read it when `total` changes:

```
var totalChange = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#total'), 'input');

var totalValue = totalChange.map(function () {
  return parseInt($('#total').val(), 10);
});

var price = totalValue.map(function (total) {
    var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val(), 10);
    return total / quantity;
});

price.subscribe(function (p) {
  $('#price').text(p);
});

// or, more succinctly with a single map operation:
var totalChange = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#total'), 'input');
var price = totalChange.map(function () {
    var total = parseInt($('#total').val(), 10);
    var quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val(), 10);
    return total / quantity;
});
price.subscribe(function (p) {
  $('#price').text(p);
});
```

Comment: quantity can be observed, hence it's observable. It's enough that it has a readable value. It's better to be functional rather than relying on closures to get the values for `total` and `quantity` in the map operation. Also, `withLatestFrom` can be understood as `a.mapWithLatestFrom(b, selector)` since the results are emitted at the same times as in `a.map()`.